# Run task only if another task wasn't UP-TO-DATE

Tags: gradle

I'm new to gradle, but I can't find this issue addressed anywhere in the way I descibe here:

1) I have a task `versionUpdate` that increments a build number counter in a number of files. (The task is arbitrary; My question is about defining complex graph dependencies.)

2) I only want `versionUpdate` to execute if the `compile` task is not UP-TO-DATE. This is a multi-project build, and it needs to happen if any subproject builds, and only once.

3) `versionUpdate` should happen *before* `compile` (as it must reflect the current build number), but if and only if `compile` was added to the graph. That is, not all tasks should be invoking `versionUpdate`, and even `compile` is conditional.

Currently, I just have the following:

```
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.dependsOn versionUpdate
```

TL;DR **How can I ask the `compile` task if it's UP-TO-DATE and modify the task graph based upon this information?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by adding a `doFirst` block to the `compileJava` task:

```
compileJava.doFirst {
    // your code to update versions goes here
}
```

This will only be executed if `compileJava` actually has work to do

Comment: Are you saying you have a multimodule build but you want to update version files if ANY submodule builds? It might help to clarify your exact requirements

Comment: The `doFirst` call isn't working as per my intentions. I added it to a subproject's `compileJava`, but if that task is up-to-date then `versionUpdate` is skipped along w/it.

Comment: Got it by manually invoking execute() on the task, as otherwise the ordering wasn't consistent for some reason.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't pick up on that.  You can't just invoke a task by calling it- I should have made it clear you'd need to do it as a function, not a task